# Why this DeleteView doesn't actually delete the entry in Django?

Tags: python, django, database

In my Django app the delete view doesn't work. When I click on an entry the page just refreshes and nothing happens. The entry is not deleted from the database. Creating and updating entries works fine. Is there something wrong with any of the files?

microtarjetas/views.py:

```
class DeleteCardView(DeleteView):
   model = Card
   template_name = 'microtarjetas/delete_card.html'
   form_class = CardForm
   success_url = '/cards/'
```

templates/microtarjetas/delete_card.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %}
<h2>Delete card</h2>
<p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

a snippet from templates/microtarjetas/cards.html:

```
       <tbody>
           {% for card in cards %}
           <tr>
               <td>{{ card.word_en }}</td>
               <td>{{ card.word_es }}</td>
               <td><a href="{% url 'update_card' card.pk %}">update</a></td>
               <td><a href="{% url 'delete_card' card.pk %}">X</a></td>
           </tr>
           {% endfor %}
       </tbody>
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Card

class CardForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Card
       fields = "__all__"
```

models.py:

```
class Card(models.Model):
   word_en = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   word_es = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
  
   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return "/cards"
 
   def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.word_en} --- {self.word_es}"
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
 
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
   path('cards/', views.CardsView.as_view(), name='cards'),
   path('cards/new', views.CreateCardView.as_view(), name='create_card'),
   path('cards/<pk>/delete/', views.DeleteCardView.as_view(), name='delete_card'),
   path('cards/<pk>/update/', views.UpdateCardView.as_view(), name='update_card'),
]
```

I add a {{ form }} tag to the delete_card.html form, it works (although it adds two input fields to the form which are unnecessary):
[delete_card.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBr1r.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are not submitting the form with the form data. You should update the code like this:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       {{ form }}
       <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView).

Comment: Thank you! It helped, and also I needed to create a new form, DeleteCardForm that had a fields=[].